# Perl : Bareword found where operator expected

Tags: perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $fh, '<', 'eg')
or die("Can't open fileC: $!\n");

while (<$fh>) {


perl -ne '($host, $port, @ip) = split /[=;.]/; print if $port != 50000+200*$i[2]+$ip[3]' eg;

}
```

In this code I am receiving an error :

```
Bareword found where operator expected at qeg.pl line 15, near "'($host, $port, @ip) = split /[=;.]/; print if $port != 50000+200*$i[2]+$ip[3]' eg"
    (Missing operator before eg?)
```

Comment: Post the real script. and some sample input.

Comment: what OS and shell are you using? cmd.exe on Windows? Or bash on Linux?

Comment: I am using lunux Ubuntu.

Comment: You are launching another perl in your program and doing it wrongly. If you want to launch another perl use **``**

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
perl -ne '($host, $port, @ip) = split /[=;.]/; print if $port != 50000+200*$i[2]+$ip[3]' eg;
```

to

```
my ($host, $port, @ip) = split /[=;.]/;
print if $port != 50000+200*$ip[2]+$ip[3];
```

and try again.

Comment: There is no variable `@i`, so that is probably supposed to be `$ip[2]`.